# How to automatically populate fields in a specific form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm developing a django app to keep track of orders and products in my laboratory. I have an Order model that I create instances from with a form that fills some of its fields (but not all) and creates an object.
I've also created an UpdateForm to update the blank fields once the order arrives to the lab. This update form has just one field (storage location), but I want this form to automatically set the status of the order to "received" and populate the "received_by" field with the logged user and "received_date" with the dateTime when the form is sent..

While writing this I just thought I could create a different model for Receive and relate it to the Order model via OnetoOne, would that be a proper solution?

How my code looks like:

```
#models.py-------------------------------------------------------------
class Pedido(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text=_('Nombre del producto.'))
    referencia = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text=_('Referencia del fabricante.'))
    cpm = models.CharField(max_length=20, default ='A la espera.',help_text=_('Código del CPM asignado a este pedido.'), null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = _('CPM'))
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    unidades = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True)
    autogestion = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name='Autogestión', help_text = _("Marca esta casilla si vas a procesar tu mismo el pedido."))
    usuario_recepcion = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='recepcion')
    fecha_recepcion = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    ESTADO_PEDIDO = (
        ('n', _('Pendiente')),
        ('p', _('Proforma solicitada')),
        ('c', _('CPM solicitado')),
        ('v', _('Para validar')),
        ('r', _('Recibido'))
    )

    estado = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=ESTADO_PEDIDO,
        blank=False,
        default='n',
        help_text=_('Estado del pedido'),
    )

    fabricante = models.ForeignKey('Fabricante', null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    centro_gasto = models.ForeignKey('CentroGasto', null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name = _('Centro de Gasto'))
    almacen = models.ForeignKey('Almacen', null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank = True)
    direccion = models.ForeignKey('Direccion', default = 'CIBM', null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name = _('Dirección de entrega'))
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default=keygen())

#views.py----------------------------------------------------------
class PedidoListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Pedido
    ordering = ['-fecha']

class PedidoDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Pedido

@login_required
def Guia(request):
    return render(request, 'guia.html')

@login_required
def add_pedido(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PedidoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.usuario = request.user
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = PedidoForm()
        return render(request, "nuevo_pedido.html", {'form': form})

class RecepcionUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Pedido
    fields = ['almacen']
    template_name_suffix = '_recepcionar'

#forms.py-----------------------------------------------------------------
class PedidoForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_usuario(self):
        if not self.cleaned_data['usuario']:
            return User()
        return self.cleaned_data['user']

    class Meta:
        model = Pedido
        exclude = ['codigo', 'fecha', 'cpm', 'almacen', 'estado', 'usuario']
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? P.S. Each Django form field has `initial` property.

Comment: Thing is I'm using a predefined view from Django (UpdateView) and it creates a form automatically, so I don't know where to add the initial value (or even if it's possible). I tried creating a form, but one of the fields is a ForeignKey to another model and I can't seem to set the needed initial value.

Comment: Can you post how your code looks like (especially models and forms in question)?

Comment: Hello @PawelKam, I just updated the question with the code, I hope it's useful, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to change predefined class in Django, it's always possible to overwrite it. For example, you could extend the form_valid method:

```
class RecepcionUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Pedido
    fields = ['almacen']
    template_name_suffix = '_recepcionar'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        super(RecepcionUpdate, self).save(form)
```

Note: I have not tested this, it is probable that  instead of calling `super().save(form)` you should `return super().form_valid(form)`. Anyways, I'm sure that with this example you'll be able to find plenty of code snippets matching your Django version.

Comment: This is what I actually went for, I just had to change the django predefined UpdateView and create manually a form. But it worked, so thanks!